# Running CodedUI Test Generated From Manual Test's Action Recordings

Tags: visual-studio-2010, coded-ui-tests, testcase

I have got a problem about running codedui test which was generated from manual test's action recordings.

When i try to run, i get this error.

The unit test adapter failed to connect to the data source or to read the data. For more information on troubleshooting this error, see "Troubleshooting Data-Driven Unit Tests" (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=62412) in the MSDN Library.
Error details: Invalid Test Case ID - 2120

But i know there is a test case that's ID is 2120 (so Visual Studio could generate it from test case)

I checked the DataSource attribute and it is correct,too.
The datasource attribute is below.
[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.TestCase", "http://tfs2010:8080/tfs/defaultcollection;Cynergy", "2113", DataAccessMethod.Sequential), TestMethod]

I couldn't find anything about this.
Any one can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched about this error and i couldn't find anything.

I recreated CodedUITest for several times but i couldn't fix. After that i delete the Test Project and create again. 
After this the problem was solved..

I don't know why i got this error and i don't know why it was solved.